# Как показать определенный div только один раз на сайте(на сеанс)?

Tags: php, javascript, html, cookie

Мне необходимо, чтобы конкретную рекламу адсенсе пользователю показывать всего 1 раз, то есть после перехода его, больше не показывать, но после перезапуска браузера реклама снова бы показывалась.

Comment: `sessionStorage` - https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Можете пожалуйста для чайника показать пример, куда тут пихнуть рекламу гоогле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/1knv6d29/  - работающий пример

```js
if (sessionStorage.beenHere) {
  document.querySelector(".once-per-session").style.display = "none";
}
sessionStorage.beenHere = true;
```

```css
.once-per-session {
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="once-per-session">Once per session.</div>
```

Comment: И в место "Once per session" поставить рекламный код адсенсе ?) Простите я просто совсем новичок

Comment: https://ibb.co/gpJzxT
Вот так, и вес это код поставить вместо кода адсенсе ?

Comment: И вместо блока адсенсе будет пустое место(после перехода)? или нижние блоки сайта поднимутся вверх место него

Comment: И еше вот что( 
Ваши изменения в коде PHP были отменены из за ошибки на строке
Исправьте и попробуйте пересохранить.

syntax error, unexpected '='